# how do I extract a vector named with the rownames from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with some meaningful rownames. I would like to extract one column from it as a vector and this vector should inherit the rownames so that it is a named vector. This vector should be fed into a function that expects a named vector as input. I want to use this vector in a tapply so attaching the names in a second step doesn't really work.

Example code:

```
my_function <- function(x){
  print(names(x[x>mean(x)]))
}

test.frame <- data.frame(nr=1:10, factor=rep(c("A", "B"), 5))
rownames(test.frame) <- letters[1:10]

tapply(test.frame$nr, test.frame$factor, my_function)
```

In this case my_function is applied to the two unnamed vectors 1:5 and 6:10. What I would like is that the function instead gets vectors that still have the names letters[1:5] and letters[6:10] from the rownames attached to it.

One way I could achieve this is to change the function so that instead of a named vector it expects a 2 column data.frame with the first column the names and the second one the numbers but that seems clumsy. So maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setNames` to get a named vector:

```
tapply(setNames(test.frame$nr, rownames(test.frame))
     , test.frame$factor, my_function)
#[1] "g" "i"
#[1] "h" "j"
#$A
#[1] "g" "i"
#
#$B
#[1] "h" "j"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to extract a named vector from a data frame where the vector's names are taken from the row names of the data frame.

The problem is that normally if you store a named vector inside a data frame, it loses its `names` attribute.

```r
x <- 1:5
names(x) <- letters[1:5]
x
#> a b c d e 
#> 1 2 3 4 5
attributes(x)
#> $`names`
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
df <- data.frame(x = x)
attributes(df$x)
#> NULL
```

However, it doesn't lose its `names` attribute if you specify that the named vector should be preserved "as is" using the function `I()`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = I(x))
attributes(df$x)
#> $`names`
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "AsIs"
```

That means if you want the columns in your data frame to all be named vectors, you need to label them all as such, using a function like this:

```
with_names <- function(df) 
{
  as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {names(x) <- row.names(df); return(x)}))
}
```

Now you have

```
df <- with_names(df)
df$x
#> a b c d e 
#> 1 2 3 4 5
```

So your row names can be used in any of the vectors taken from `df`:

```r
tapply(df$x, c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1), names)
#> $`1`
#> [1] "a" "c" "e"
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] "b" "d"
```